# Abnormal build process termination" issue in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

How to solve the problem when even running the Hello World program for the first time, it cannot open, and I receive the error message "Abnormal build process termination"?

[image]

I have a full version licensed for students, and I downloaded the JDK environment within the program using the download option.

Comment: Something is blocking localhost connections on your system. Check firewall/security tools settings and the OS hosts file

Comment: I have disabled the firewalls for IntelliJ IDEA and checked the hosts file. It seems fine to me, but the problem still persists.